# Software for managing java lang .properties files for translation

Tags: java, file, properties, translation, pootle

Is there a good software for managing java .properties language files, I have tried Pootle but there u must convert to po files and back is there any other alternative?

I neead something that translators could use to translate our JSF gui via some translating software which could manage .properties files

Comment: "software"? Are you looking for a library that enables you to handle them programatically? Or a UI for editing? Or something else?

Comment: I think it's clear he needs a tool for translators to do their job. "I need something that translators could use tot translate our..."

Comment: i'm looking for a software to help translators to easily translate all our language files which are in this case .properties, for example when we develop we fill in only one language file and then I upload this to some software and use it as template for other translations, then translators translates the new entries in other languages. After the translation is complete the software should be able to export all translations in a form of properties files which I then include in our application

Answer (score 8):

Our localization team uses [poeditor.com](http://poeditor.com)
It works with `.properties` files and the thing I like most is that it integrates with the projects on GitHub.
If your project is Open Source or has less than 1000 strings, it's free of charge.

Comment: This one looks like a better option, specially for open source projects. it integrates with Github and that's a huge plus.

Answer (score 5):

We use https://webtranslateit.com/ as a hosted solution - we upload the english resource bundle with our continuous integration server, our users translate this online, and then we donwload the translated bundles. It's nice that the translators can do this online, and you have control over the files and the history.

[Managing the localization of Java properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365419/managing-the-localization-of-java-properties-files/8288939#8288939)

Best regards

Comment: Lame because you have to upload each property file individually.

Answer (score 4):

Zanata is a web-based translation platform that understands .properties files natively. It supports the standard .properties encoding (ISO-8859-1), but also non-standard utf-8 encoding since some choose to use it.

*COI declaration: I am part of the core development team for Zanata.*

If your project uses Maven, a Maven plugin is available to update source strings and translations as part of your build. Other clients are available for integrating with other build processes.

You can host open source projects on the public server (see http://zanata.org). For private development you can host your own server (see http://zanata.org/download/).

If you want more detail I'll update this answer.

Comment: For JBoss related project, use https://translate.jboss.org/

Comment: Also lame because you cannot import property files. There is some hidden command line program that you need to upload property files. You can specify your git repo but it will not import your files. Pretty nice website but lame because it will not allow you to get your property files.

Comment: @Yaza you can upload properties files through the website, with a Maven plugin, or with a command-line client. I can give you a hand or point you to the docs if you have trouble with any of those. It sounds like you want the files to be fetched from your repo automatically though.

Comment: This project is discontinued as they say on their website: "Zanata is in maintenance mode and new projects are not accepted."

Answer (score 2):

The [ResourceBundle Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-rbe/) Eclipse Plugin provides a nice GUI for editing language property files.

**Update:**
In my company we use [Multilizer](http://www2.multilizer.com/) for localizing our Delphi applications. There are tools included for external translators. In their feature matrix a Java properties file plugin is mentioned, but I have no expierence with that plugin. Maybe it's worth a look.

Comment: I nead a software for translators not for developers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you [oneskyapp.com](http://www.oneskyapp.com)

- can parse java properties (and other formats)
- hosted online
- great pricing (free for team to up to 5 collaborators)
- has api (so you can integrate in your developer flow)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a new one, called http://lokali.se.

A bit different view on project ideology and cool stuff like webhooks on export and custom zips.

Comment: looks nice but it looks it does not support .properties java files, although it should, but I gen an error  ... "this file tipe is not supported" when I upload a .properties java file

Answer (score 0):

[crowdin](https://www.crowdin.com) is an excellent resource which I have seen many popular software bases utilize. While I have never participated in the development side of using this website, I have participated in translations which have been quite simple to understand, get in, and start translating quickly. Looking at the supported software, it states that it supports exporting projects into .properties files which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I would prefer a free solution, we are still on pootle for now

Answer (score 0):

[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) is a web based translation platform which supports Java `.properties` files. I've used Transifex in multiple Java projects to localize my GUI, and I must say it really works well.

Transifex costs some money, but it's free of charge for open source projects.

Answer (score -2):

You can just add/edit to them using any text editor such as notepad++

There's also a handy [Eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-rbe/) that can be used by developers as well. Not sure if this is any good to you in this case.

Comment: I know notepad++ but I nead something for translators not for developers, something that can compare which translations are missing in other languages based on a template translation file, which would be in our case the main language .property file