# Tool for i18n with ResourceBundle in Java

Tags: java, internationalization

For an internationalized Swing application with .properties files, one per language, I need a tool to manage these .properties files.

To be more specific:
When I change a string in the default language properties file, I need a tool for translators to run in order to copy the added/changed/removed strings into their respective language files.

I found the ResourceBundle plugin for Eclipse, but I don't really want to enforce a heavy application like Eclipse on translators. It would seem like a huge overkill. A text based tool would be preferable.

[This question asker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768997/software-for-managing-java-lang-properties-files-for-translation/7769348%20this) seems to be seeking for the same tool as I do, but seems to never have found a solution.

I also found [gettext-commons](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-commons/) which is a lib that enables use of gettext po files in a Java application. If I don't find a suiting solution for managing the .properties files, I might start using this instead.

Comment: I have [a project](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple) which might interest you... At least you can write your property files in UTF-8 and you can use `printf()`. But I don't have a tool for what you want, however. Might be fun to develop! Watch out that `gettext` requires native libs.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about gettext. I was also thinking about coding a tool myself, and the cases of added and removed strings are easy, but changed strings probably require meta data of some sort. Gotta think about this a bit :-)

Comment: Gettext does not require a native lib at runtime as far as i know, the po files get compiled to java classes by the gettext tools. I have a pure java implementation of such a compiler and related tools at https://github.com/jhorstmann/i18n

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your project with [build management system](http://basmussen.github.io/i18n-maven-plugin/dependency-info.html) like maven, you can use the [i18n-maven-plugin](http://basmussen.github.io/i18n-maven-plugin/) to handle internationalization and localization easily.